# Separating vectors from linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have a linear combination of vectors as follows

$
\mathbf{s} = \alpha_1\mathbf{x}_1 + \dots + \alpha_m\mathbf{x}_m + \beta_1\mathbf{y}_1 + \dots + \beta_n\mathbf{y}_n
$

where $\alpha_i, \beta_i \forall i$ are constants, and $\mathbf{x}_i, \forall i$ lies in the null space of a matrix $\mathbf{Z}$.

Is there a way to recover the sum :
$\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i\mathbf{x}_i$ from above. I'm aware that 
$\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{s} = \sum_{i=1}^n\beta_i\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{y}_i$.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{s} = \sum_{i=1}^n\beta_i\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{y}_i$?

Comment: @MichaelM. Yes, thank you. Corrected that.

Comment: Do we know anything about the $\mathbf x_k$'s and $\mathbf y_k$'s? Are they linearly independent?

Comment: Well $\mathbf{x}_k$'s are not necessarily linearly independent, in some circumstances, 2 or more of them may be the same. However $\mathbf{y}_k$'s can be considered linearly independent of each other and the $\mathbf{x}_k$'s.

Comment: And where do these vectors live?

Comment: N dimensional real space.

Comment: Is there a relationship between $N$, $m$, and $n$?

Comment: Nope. I am open to suggestions though about possible restrictions on these vectors. I will alter the problem formulation!

Answer (score 1):

We are given vectors $x_1,\dotsc,x_m,y_1,\dotsc,y_n\in\Bbb R^N$ so that $\{y_1,\dotsc,y_n\}$ is linearly independent and 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}
\Span\{x_1,\dotsc,x_m\}\cap\Span\{y_1,\dotsc,y_n\}=\{\vec 0\}
$$
Let $\Phi$ be the $N\times(m+n)$ matrix
$$
\Phi=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & \dotsb & x_m & y_1 & \dotsb & y_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, suppose the following condition is met.

*Assumption.* $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}N<m+n$ and $\rank(\Phi)=N$

This assumption guarentees that $\Phi$ has a *[right inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element#Matrices)* defined by
$$
\Phi_{\text{right}}^{-1}=\Phi^\top(\Phi\Phi^\top)^{-1}
$$
satisfying $\Phi\Phi_{\text{right}}^{-1}=I_N$.

Now, let 
$$
\Psi=\begin{bmatrix}x_1&\dotsb&x_m&\vec 0_{N\times n}\end{bmatrix}
$$
and consider the equation
$$
T\Phi=\Psi\tag{1}
$$
Applying $\Phi_{\text{right}}^{-1}$ on the right of (1) gives
$$
T=\Psi\Phi_{\text{right}}^{-1}
$$
Here $T$ satisfies $T(x_k)=x_k$ and $T(y_k)=\vec 0$. Hence
\begin{align*}
T\vec s
&= T(\alpha_1 x_1+\dotsb+\alpha_m x_m+\beta_1y_1+\dotsb+\beta_ny_n) \\
&= \alpha_1 T(x_1)+\dotsb+\alpha_m T(x_m)+\beta_1 T(y_1)+\dotsb+\beta_n T(y_n) \\
&= \alpha_1 x_1+\dotsb+\alpha_m T(x_m)+\beta_1\vec 0+\dotsb+\beta_n\vec 0 \\
&= \alpha_1 x_1+\dotsb+\alpha_m x_m
\end{align*}

Comment: This looks great man! I'll see if this fits into the larger picture. Thanks for the answer. I see that you're a graduate student as well!

Comment: Going by the assumption $rank(\Phi)=N$, if all the $\mathbf{x}_k$'s are the same, then there should be $N$ independent $\mathbf{y}_k$'s, am I right?

Comment: I don't think so..........

Comment: Oops, my bad! I confused the rows & columns!

Comment: I completely overlooked it, but I do not have the individual vectors to begin with. Just the linear combination $\mathbf{s}$. Maybe I wasn't explicit enough.